# "if" statement, condition will never be executed

Tags: swift, if-statement, swift3

I thought I was good with if statements but apparently Im still missing something. In the line `timer.invalidate()` the compiler complains

> Will never be executed

As far as I can tell my syntax is correct.

```
@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {

    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:0.2 , target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.imageSwitch) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    var buttonState = false

    if buttonState == true {
        timer.invalidate()
        buttonState = false
    }
    if buttonState == false {
        timer.fire()
        buttonState = true
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are setting `buttonState` to false, then checking whether it is true. Of course it will not be true.

Comment: Remove this line `var buttonState = false` and add it outside the method `@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any)`.

Comment: you need to set var buttonState = false global to view controller, otherwise this condition never true.

Comment: can you add code of ViewController.imageSwitch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move the declaration of `buttonState` out of the method. And then simplify the `if` conditions:

```
var buttonState = false

 @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:0.2 , target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.imageSwitch) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    if buttonState {
        timer.invalidate()
        buttonState = false
    } else {
        timer.fire()
        buttonState = true
    }
}
```

You should additionally ask yourself what the methods is even supposed to do, do you want the `buttonState` to continously switch from `true` to `false` and back *or* do you want it to do *something* else (like switching to to another value after a delay)? In the first case you should declare the timer outside the method and let it run there, never invalidate it - in the second case you should move the timer declaration inside the `else` block and turn `repeat` off. In both cases you should probably remove the `timer.invalidate()` and `timer.fire()` calls.

Comment: I would add that the contents of the method still don't make sense :)

Comment: @Sulthan are you referring to the `timer` handling?

Comment: Exactly. It would have to be also declared outside the scope otherwise you cannot invalidate and `timer.fire()` just does not make sense.

Comment: yeah I noticed it does not work still. My logic is still flawed but I'll get there. Thanks for the help

Answer (score -2):

Full solution :

```
var timerState = false
var timer = Timer()

@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    if timerState == false {
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:0.2 , target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.imageSwitch) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timerState = true
    } else {
        timer.invalidate()
        timerState = false
```